# Blender to UDK 3 How to smooth Static Mesh

Tags: blender, udk, modelling-techniques

I've created a bed cover model for my small game and here is how it looks like in blender:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mramb.jpg

but whenever I import it to UDK it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuIVE.jpg

it looks smooth in Blender but when I import to the Udk it doesn't 
Why is this happening? And 
I use .fbx to export from blender...

Comment: It looks the same. I think you just need to assign a proper material for that mesh.

Comment: I tried it with texture on it still looks same like instead of smooth, its square

Comment: It's not about the texture, but about the material and rendering technique - the way object's surface interacts with the light. Right now it's completely flat.